# yepnope / modernizr.load global complete callback?

Tags: javascript, modernizr, assets, yepnope

Is it possible to fire a global complete callback once ALL files have loaded? Ex:

```
yepnope(['file1.js', 'file2.js'])
```

....some html....

```
<script>
    yepnope({complete: function() { console.log('This is getting called before the above files finish loading') });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
Modernizr.load([

  {
  load : ["file1.js", "file2.js"],
  complete : function()
  {
  // do some stuff
  }
  } // can repeat this block as required

]);
```

Good luck!